# Are XML and XSLT a viable option for creating a web interface for a hardware device?

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got a piece of hardware for which we're looking to create a web control interface.  This hardware currently utilizes eCOS to control the web interface/HTML generation and I'm interested in potentially getting away from that.

I'm unfamiliar with web programming, but thought that XML and XSLT would be a potential path for this. The big design requirement is that the user not have to be running anything other than an off-the-shelf browser like Firefox or IE.

When the web server gets a request, do I simply send the XML and XSLT files, does the XSLT file have to be present on the user's machine, or does the XSLT file perform the transform within the web server before sending HTML?

I know that's a painfully simply question for those with more experience, but I throw myself at your mercy in the hopes of some assistance.

Comment: I think this belongs to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Alejandro: I'm a far cry from a "Power User", but the application is probably appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In can be done either way - in many ways, it is better to transform on the server, as you can't ensure browser compatibility.

XSLT transformations are possible on recent versions of both IE and Firefox (simply add a reference to the stylesheet to your XML document - it can be a remote URL). However, support varies between the browsers and the different versions.

In order to ensure that you know what the browser gets, I would transform on the server (possibly caching the transform results).

Comment: @Oded: "XSLT transformations are possible on" every major browser like IE 6,7,8, FF, Opera, Safary and Chrome. All strictly following the standar.

Comment: @Alejandro - I wasn't sure about Opera, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @Oded: My boss is going to like the idea of leaving less to the "imagination" of the browser anyway, so I will likely transform on the server.

Comment: @Rich - just to rest your mind regarding feasibility of the approach, I had worked on a commerce site that was doing XSLT transformations on the server. It wasn't the largest site, but did handle hundreds of connections a second.

Comment: @Rich Hoffman: I don't think it is left to browsers imagination. Check my old cross browser XML/XSLT driven site at http://www.aranedabienesraices.com.ar

Comment: @Alejandro: Understood.  I was being "tongue-in-cheek" about it.  I always cringe trying to anticipate the reactions of bosses.

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer, which you might or might not find helpful, concerning building large sites and webapps with a helping hand of XML/XSLT.

So how we do it, how it can be done, just sharing experience.

**Backend**

Backend programmers make high-level business logic. The result is XML data available via http.

**Frontend**

A dialect of XML is used to make http calls to acquire XML data that comes from different sources. There are also a lot of other things like working with Request/Protocol/Cookies, kind of local datastorage (e.g. own scope for creating/setting "variables"), caching, threading and so on.

Thus an XML document for every particular page is created in realtime (except of cached parts, of course). Common parts are shared via XInclude.

Then it comes to XSLT. Well, nothing unusual here, except that an appreciable part of business logic is created. All in all it's a transforming of acquired XML input into HTML/CSS representation.

XSLT is mainly done on serverside, rather than on client.

This all is the area of responsibility of UI programmers.

**Clientside**

JS containing user experience logic is written by UI programmers aswell.
 AJAX calls, for example, go to XML gates, created on frontend, where backend response may be conviniently converted into HTML, JSON or anything else via XSLT, and than used on client.

**Whole picture**

User goes to a page (index.xml or index/ or you name it), XML data is collected from various sources, resulting XML is made and than transformed to HTML/CSS via XSLT. No visible indicators for a user, that XSLT even was there.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO XSLT works well with 'read only' browser views, where the main concern is formatting of page data.

However, IMHO XSLT becomes icky very quickly when you need to build rich client interfaces, as you need to contain different languages HTML, js / jquery etc

Re : Where to do the XSLT - you can do the transform on the server yourself (and render HTML), or you can send the xml down to the browser with the Linked XSL reference

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myxsl.xsl"?>
```

Comment: Yeah.  That's where my unfamiliarity with web "stuff" got me.  I recognize the 'href' now and should have assumed that it could link to the transform on the server.  Thanks.